# jQuery event handler with multiple links won't work

Tags: jquery, html, event-handling

I'm trying to append the jQuery ui-datepicker and I can't get the event handler working:

```
$( '.ui-datepicker' ).on('click', 'a.ui-datepicker-next', 'a.ui-datepicker-prev', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
        console.log("CLICK");
});
```

I've got nothing logging to the console when I click the links. Here is the html:

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"...>
    <div class="ui-datepicker-header ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix- ui-corner-all">
        <a class="ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all"...></a>
        <a class="ui-datepicker-prev ui-corner-all"...></a>
        ...
```

What do I need to put as the event handler to trigger this? The jQuery is in a `<script>jQuery here</script>` in the footer of my html.

**EDIT:** links were incorrect - `a.ui-datepicker-month` and `a.ui-datepicker-year` *changed to* `a.ui-datepicker-next` and `a.ui-datepicker-prev`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right. The selectors need to be comma delimited but in the same string. Try this:

```
$('.ui-datepicker').on('click', 'a.ui-datepicker-month, a.ui-datepicker-year', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("CLICK");
});
```

Note: `'a.ui-datepicker-month, a.ui-datepicker-year'`. Also note the use of `e`, not `event`, as that will override the global event object that some browsers have.

*Update after question was edited:

There's two other issues. Firstly the correct classes are `a.ui-datepicker-prev` and `a.ui-datepicker-next`. Also, the `ui.-datepicker` element doesn't exist on load of the DOM, hence there's nothing to bind the event to. To fix this you can use `$(document)`, although ideally you should use the nearest parent element to those you want to target thats in the DOM on load. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.ui-datepicker-prev, a.ui-datepicker-next', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("CLICK");
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2bvbheL1/)

Comment: Corrected the syntax. Still not logging to the console though.... @Rory McCrossan

Comment: There's nothing specifically wrong with your code. The issue must lay with how the event is attached. Does the `.ui-datepicker` element exist when you execute the above code? As a test, try replacing `$('.ui-datepicker')` with `$(document)`

Comment: Neither of the `<a>` elements in the edit have a class of `ui-datepicker-month` or `ui-datepicker-year`...?

Comment: My mistake. I meant the next and prev links which are in the html: see edit above - sorry @Rory McCrossan

Comment: It's because the `.ui-datepicker` class isn't in the DOM when the page loads. As I mentioned, if you use `$(document)` instead, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/2bvbheL1/. The key here is that the element in the primary selector *has* to exist in the DOM when you attach the event handler.

Comment: That did it! Thank you, if you edit above I can accept the answer :)